# Missing data in Boxplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

The original `dataset` contain 4 data named df1,df2,df3,df4(all in pandas dataframe format)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("./df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("./df2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("./df3.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("./df4.csv")
    # Concat these data 
dataset = [df1,df2, df3,df4]


# Plottting 
fig = plt.figure()
bpl = plt.boxplot(dataset, positions=np.array(xrange(len(dataset)))*2.0-0.4, \
                          sym='+', widths=0.5, patch_artist=True)

plt.show()
```

But the first data `df1` was missing. I check `df1`, find nothing abnormal.

[image]

I upload these 4 data [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQWEhubzRFTmxTQ2M&usp=sharing) in .csv format.
 Any advice would be appreciate!

#### Update

[image]

Comment: It is better if you post code that actually runs and reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have corrected my question.

Comment: Sorry, I use these sentences in ipython notebook. I have corrected it, too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I could make the plot without any problem.

Comment: I used his code except xrange() -> np.arange(). xrange has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: The above plot is more appropriate as a comment than an answer. But I don't think I can attach a plot in comment. So, it ended up at answer section.

Comment: Sorry, but what is problem, if you add your code? I would like upvote your answer, but without testing your code is it impossible.

Comment: Btw, I try change `xrange() -> np.arange()` and I dont get your output. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for @Sung Figure. I use your solution, with changing `xarange` to `np.arange`. The figure still look wrong.