# Missing boxplot by category with plt.boxplot - (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to do a boxplot with two categories, but for a reason it doesn't appear de second boxplot. Here my code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Data
url  = 'https://github.com/Nayeli-Luis/stackoverflow_collection/blob/main/datasets/knz_bison.csv?raw=true'
bison = pd.read_csv(url)

# Prepare data
bisonF = bison.loc[bison['animal_sex'] == "F"].animal_weight.tolist()
bisonM = bison.loc[bison['animal_sex'] == "M"].animal_weight.tolist()
bison_sex = [bisonM, bisonF]
```

At this point `bison_sex` is a list with two lists. Then de plot:

```py
plt.boxplot(bison_sex)
```

And here I get this:

```
{'whiskers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff67829b460>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff67829b940>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cdeca0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677ce3490>],
 'caps': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cde0a0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cde7c0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677ce31f0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677ce3c40>],
 'boxes': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff67829b370>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cdee80>],
 'medians': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cde5b0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677ce3e80>],
 'fliers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677cdea60>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff677ce36d0>],
 'means': []}
```

[image]

And I don't understand what happens. I know to do this with `pandas` and `seaborn` but I need to do it with `matplotlib`.

I've alredy restarted the python kernel, and I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276074/missing-data-in-boxplot-using-matplotlib) similar question but It isn't my case

Comment: There's a `NaN` in `bisonM`.

Comment: @BigBen duuuh! that's right! Thank you

Comment: `sns.boxplot(data=bison, y='animal_weight', x='animal_sex')` is easier because there's no need to separate the data, and because it ignores `NaN` values. seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib.

Comment: You can also pivot the dataframe and plot `bison.pivot(columns='animal_sex', values='animal_weight').plot(kind='box')`, which ignores/filters the NaN values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as @BigBen said I had a `NaN`. So... here the solution:

1. I decided to use Series instead of lists

```py
bisonF = bison.loc[bison['animal_sex'] == "F"].animal_weight
bisonM = bison.loc[bison['animal_sex'] == "M"].animal_weight
```

2. Count `NaN`:

```py
sum(np.isnan(bisonM))
```

3. Delete `NaN`:

```py
bisonM = bisonM[~np.isnan(bisonM)]
```

4. Remake list

```py
bison_sex = [bisonM, bisonF]
```

5. Plot

```py
plt.boxplot(bison_sex)
```

And ready!

[image]